# Why importance is affected after parallelization of randomForest?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest, parallel-foreach

I am working now with the randomForest package in R. To speed up the classification step, I was interested in performing the forest in parallel. For that, I have used the package 'foreach' in a similar way that it is indicated on the 'foreach' vignette. This consists in splitting the total number of trees by the number of cores you would like to use, and then combining them with the function 'combine' of the package 'randomForest':

```
require(randomForest)
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=CPUS)
rf  <- foreach::foreach(ntree=rep(ceiling(NTREE/CPUS), CPUS), .combine=randomForest::combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
    randomForest::randomForest(x=t(Y), y=A, ntree=ntree, importance=TRUE, ...)
    }
```

I compared the results of the "parallel" forest with the forest generated in one core. The prediction capacity with the test set seems to be similar, but the 'importance' values are considerably reduced, and this affects the following steps of variable selection.

```
imp <- importance(rf,type=1)
```

I would like to know why this happens, and if it is correct or there is any mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code seems to be correct, according to this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf. I've checked it on randomly generated example. Importance does seem a little bit different, but it also changes a little when training forests with same parameters. I don't think this is a mistake, but you could post a reproducible example to prove me wrong

Comment: Yeah, differences could definitely just be due to the random nature of the algorithm, depending on what your NTREE value is, as well as the dimensionality of your data.  Have you verified that this consistently occurs?

Answer (score 1):

randomForest::combine does not support re-calculation of variable importance. In randomForest package importance is only calculated just before randomForest::randomForest function terminates. Two options are:

- Write your own variable importance function, which will take the combined forest and training set as inputs. That is roundly ~50 lines of code.
- Use a 'lapply'-like parallel computation, where each randomForest object is an element in the output list. Next aggregate variable importance across all forests and simply compute the mean. Use do.call(rf.list,combine) outside foreach loop instead. This method is an approximation of the total variable importance, but a quite good one.

Windows supported code example:

```
library(randomForest)
library(doParallel)
CPUS=6; NTREE=5000
cl = makeCluster(CPUS)
registerDoParallel(cl)
data(iris)
rf.list = foreach(ntree = rep(NTREE/CPUS,CPUS),
                  .combine=c,
                  .packages="randomForest") %dopar% {
                    list(randomForest(Species~.,data=iris,importance=TRUE, ntree=ntree))  
                  }
stopCluster(cl)
big.rf = do.call(combine,rf.list)
big.rf$importance = rf.list[[1]]$importance
for(i in 2:CPUS) big.rf$importance = big.rf$importance + rf.list[[i]]$importance
big.rf$importance  = big.rf$importance / CPUS
varImpPlot(big.rf)

#test number of trees in one forest and combined forest, big.rf
print(big.rf)  #5000 trees
rf.list[[1]]$ntree 

#training single forest
rf.single = randomForest(Species~.,data=iris,ntree=5000,importance=T)
varImpPlot(big.rf)
varImpPlot(rf.single)
#print unscaled variable importance, no large deviations
print(big.rf$importance)

# setosa  versicolor  virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
# Sepal.Length 0.033184860 0.023506673 0.04043017           0.03241500         9.679552
# Sepal.Width  0.008247786 0.002135783 0.00817186           0.00613059         2.358298
# Petal.Length 0.335508637 0.304525644 0.29786704           0.30933142        43.160074
# Petal.Width  0.330610910 0.307016328 0.27129746           0.30023245        44.043737

print(rf.single$importance)

# setosa   versicolor  virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
# Sepal.Length 0.031771614 0.0236603417 0.03782824          0.031049531         9.516198
# Sepal.Width  0.008436457 0.0009236979 0.00880401          0.006048261         2.327478
# Petal.Length 0.341879367 0.3090482654 0.29766905          0.312507316        43.786481
# Petal.Width  0.322015885 0.3045458852 0.26885097          0.296227150        43.623370

#but when plotting using varImppLot, scale=TRUE by default
#either simply turn of scaling to get comparable results
varImpPlot(big.rf,scale=F)
varImpPlot(rf.single,scale=F)

#... or correct scaling to the number of trees
big.rf$importanceSD = CPUS^-.5 * big.rf$importanceSD 


#and now there are no large differences for scaled variable importance either
varImpPlot(big.rf,scale=T)
varImpPlot(rf.single,scale=T)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Soren! I am trying to implement 'solution 2' but I have found a problem. The parallel random forest is inside a function, and I am not able to make the function to get the appropriate number of trees: it performs 500 trees (default) per core an not the rep(CPUS/NTREE, CPUS) trees...

Comment: Oh forgot ntree=ntree

Comment: ok the code has been fixed, when randomForest is called within the parallel foreach loop, you can change all parameters as you like, you can even refer to non exported constants outside the loop. Have fun :)

Comment: ok! I corrected and it worked, but I am afraid I do not obtain the same results as the results of the not parallel random forest. Importances are different so the variables I obtain are different.

Comment: That's probably because your looking on scaled variable importance, without correcting importanceSD. I have changed the code to show, that the raw importance is very very similar. Also the code shows how to correct importanceSD

Comment: I am not sure if it is related, but I was extracting the importance with the function 'importance(rf, type=1)', but I checked and it is not equal to rf$importance[, "MeanDecreaseAccuracy"]...

Comment: exactly, importance() has scale=T by default